# How to split a pyspark dataframe column into only two columns (example below)?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, split, apache-spark-sql

The column has multiple usage of the delimiter in a single row, hence `split` is not as straightforward.
Upon splitting, only the **1st delimiter** occurrence has to be considered in this case.

As of now, I am doing this.

*However, I feel there can be a better solution*?

```
testdf= spark.createDataFrame([("Dog", "meat,bread,milk"), ("Cat", "mouse,fish")],["Animal", "Food"])

testdf.show()

+------+---------------+
|Animal|           Food|
+------+---------------+
|   Dog|meat,bread,milk|
|   Cat|     mouse,fish|
+------+---------------+

testdf.withColumn("Food1", split(col("Food"), ",").getItem(0))\
        .withColumn("Food2",expr("regexp_replace(Food, Food1, '')"))\
        .withColumn("Food2",expr("substring(Food2, 2)")).show()

+------+---------------+-----+----------+
|Animal|           Food|Food1|     Food2|
+------+---------------+-----+----------+
|   Dog|meat,bread,milk| meat|bread,milk|
|   Cat|     mouse,fish|mouse|      fish|
+------+---------------+-----+----------+
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An approach using regular expression to split only first occurrence from the list

```
testdf.withColumn('Food1',f.split('Food',"(?<=^[^,]*)\\,")[0]).\
       withColumn('Food2',f.split('Food',"(?<=^[^,]*)\\,")[1]).show()

+------+---------------+-----+----------+
|Animal|           Food|Food1|     Food2|
+------+---------------+-----+----------+
|   Dog|meat,bread,milk| meat|bread,milk|
|   Cat|     mouse,fish|mouse|      fish|
+------+---------------+-----+----------+
```

Comment: I have now actually accepted this answer, because it handles the corner case when there isn't even 1 comma. (Cow, grass) would be split into (Cow,grass,grass,null) for our example.

Comment: @ Shubham - you mind providing an explanation for the regex? (in case someone has a different delimiter)

Answer (score 5):

I would just use **`string functions`**, dont see a reason to use regex.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

testdf\
      .withColumn("Food1", F.expr("""substring(Food,1,instr(Food,',')-1)"""))\
      .withColumn("Food2", F.expr("""substring(Food,instr(Food,',')+1,length(Food))""")).show()

#+------+---------------+-----+----------+
#|Animal|           Food|Food1|     Food2|
#+------+---------------+-----+----------+
#|   Dog|meat,bread,milk| meat|bread,milk|
#|   Cat|     mouse,fish|mouse|      fish|
#+------+---------------+-----+----------+*
```

Comment: This works perfectly fine. But is it possible to return `null` if  the delimiter is not present in the string?

Answer (score 3):

A slightly different approach is to use [slice](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#slice) and [trim](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#trim):

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import expr, split

df.withColumn("food_ar", split("food", ",")) \
  .select( \
         df.Animal,
         df.Food,
         expr("food_ar[0]").alias("Food1"),
         expr("trim('[]', string(slice(food_ar, 2, size(food_ar) - 1)))").alias("Food2"))

# +------+---------------+-----+----------+
# |Animal|           Food|Food1|     Food2|
# +------+---------------+-----+----------+
# |   Dog|meat,bread,milk| meat|bread,milk|
# |   Cat|     mouse,fish|mouse|      fish|
# +------+---------------+-----+----------+
```

First use `split` first as you already did to generate the array. Next we access the items using single Spark SQL accessor `a[0]` to populate the *head* and `slice` together with `trim` for the *tail* of the array.