# splitting pyspark column only on first instance

Tags: pyspark, split

This an enrichment of the question asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62317676/how-to-split-a-pyspark-dataframe-column-into-only-two-columns-example-below).
The `substring` function works better since it is not limited only to regex characters.
However, the answer to the above question satisfies if the column to be split **always** has the delimited character.
If I have a dataframe `c1` like so:

```
+-----------------+
|             name|
+-----------------+
|      ETX2800_PM3|
|      ETX2800_PM3|
|          STP2372|
|          STP2372|
|      ETX2800_PM3|
|TRK2353_CGRA_3_35|
|TRK2353_CGRA_3_35|
```

If I use the split method:

```
c2=c1.withColumn('first split', f.expr("""substring(name,instr(name,'_')+1,length(name))"""))
```

I get

```
+-----------------+-----------+
|             name|first split|
+-----------------+-----------+
|      ETX2800_PM3|        PM3|
|      ETX2800_PM3|        PM3|
|          STP2372|    STP2372|
|          STP2372|    STP2372|
|      ETX2800_PM3|        PM3|
|TRK2353_CGRA_3_35|  CGRA_3_35|
|TRK2353_CGRA_3_35|  CGRA_3_35|
```

But I expect `null` in the 3rd and 4th rows.
Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using a `udf` which is more readable than using `regex`:

```
def fun(x):
    s = x.split("_",1)
    return s[-1] if len(s)>1 else None

myudf = F.udf(fun,StringType())
df.withColumn("Spl",myudf("name")).show()
```

---

```
+-----------------+---------+
|             name|      Spl|
+-----------------+---------+
|      ETX2800_PM3|      PM3|
|      ETX2800_PM3|      PM3|
|          STP2372|     null|
|          STP2372|     null|
|      ETX2800_PM3|      PM3|
|TRK2353_CGRA_3_35|CGRA_3_35|
|TRK2353_CGRA_3_35|CGRA_3_35|
+-----------------+---------+
```